# Freeradius-Perl script using POP3 against Gmail

Tags: perl, gmail, pop3, freeradius

has anyone successfully authenticate against gmail using pop3 perl scripts in freeradiu 3? I'm following this tutorial(https://kerker.website/freeradiusgmail802-1x%e8%a8%ad%e5%ae%9apop3s/) but perl continues rejecting the user.

This is the script:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use Mail::POP3Client;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

sub authenticate {
    my $pop = Mail::POP3Client->new(
        USER => $RAD_REQUEST{'User-Name'},
        PASSWORD => $RAD_REQUEST{'User-Password'},
        HOST => "pop.gmail.com",
        USESSL => 1,
        DEBUG => 1,
    );
    if($pop->Connect()){
        return RLM_MODULE_OK;
    }else{
        return RLM_MODULE_REJECT;
    }
    $pop->Close;
}
```

I can't post the output right now but it rejects the user and I haven't been able to debug the script. I just want to know if anyone has recently sucedded in authenticating gmail and how.

Comment: Have a look at the actual error message in the POP3 dialog you get when trying to connect with POP3 to gmail this way. It is likely that this simply isn't possible since you did not enable insecure methods with GMail. Even this is not the case - please include the debug output from POP3Client in your question so that one can get the details auf the authentication problem.